# How to copy a file without extension and at the end of the copy put it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, powershell, cmd, exe

I am using teracopy to move some files. I would like to make a form in visual * .exe where you simply have two windows: one with the file's origin on the right, and another with the file's destination.

I need to copy the file without its extension, verify that the transfer occurred without issue, and then restore the original extension. For example:

- Copy file.mov to // smb: Storage / Movies /

  - Remove the .mov extension
  - Copy the file to the storage location
  - Validate file size
  - If the file size at the destination matches the source, restore the .mov extension
  - If the file size doesn't match, delete the destination file and notify the user of the error.

The files I plan to copy are very large, and will take a good amount of time. I'm removing the extension so that users on the server will not accidentally try to access a file that isn't completely transferred yet - the idea is they see an "extensionless" file and know not to try and open it, whereas any files with extensions are certain to have copied over correctly.

I've tried using CMD and powershell, but I've only managed to copy the file or retry copying if the copy fails. I don't yet know how to remove the extension and restore it.

```
> ROBOCOPY /Mir <Source> <Target>
```

Comment: This question is not related to VB.net at all.

Comment: If you are a beginner you might start with simple script without any GUI. In Powershell you can use [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1) to copy a file and you can specify the sources and the targets fullname either with or without extension.

Comment: In an open `cmd` window, type: `for %A in (file.mov) do echo %~dpnA - %~xA` - %~zA. Analyze the output, then type `for /?` to learn what the first command did exactly. That should enable you to come up with some code, we can help you with. Currently, your question is off-topic.

Comment: ... for example `Copy-Item -Path D:\sample\sample.txt -Destination D:\sample\newSample`  ... you could check if the copy was  successful with comparing the hashes you make of both files.

Comment: What exactly is the point in removing the extension and later on add it back??

Comment: Hello friends, thanks for your reply.

The problem is that on the other side, in the destination folder I have an automation that takes the file to another side. If it is in the process of copying it fails because they are very large files.

and since Aspera Server at the time of copying the files puts at the end "file.mov.transfer" my idea is to eliminate the extension but it would also help me that at the time of the copy being launched put this extension .transfer and once copy OK leave the original file "file.mov"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
copy %UserProfile%\YourFile.* "Path to copy to"
```